# How to use a div inside a Shadow DOM as a Leaflet map container?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, custom-element

The JS based custom element below appear to work but can not find the `mapid` div that I add to the shadow DOM root. Is there a way in Leaflet or custom elements to allow stock Leaflet (version 1.4 which is the latest as of this writing) to find and use a shadow DOM-based `mapid` div?

error:

```
Uncaught Error: Map container not found.
    at NewClass._initContainer (Map.js:1102)
    at NewClass.initialize (Map.js:136)
    at new NewClass (Class.js:22)
    at Module.createMap (Map.js:1717)
    at new GDMap (gd-map.js:16)
    at gd-map.js:30
    at gd-map.js:31
```

I'm going on the approach that this simply is a case where Leaflet is looking for the mapid div in the dom root and can't find it in the shadow dom.

Javascript

```
import * as L from './leaflet/leaflet-src.esm.js';

(function () {
    class GDMap extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();

            this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
            this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<div style="height:180px" id="mapid"></div>`;

           var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

            L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'

            }).addTo(map);


            L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
                .openPopup();

        }
    }
    window.customElements.define('geodex-map', GDMap);
})();
```

edited post to align div id as pointed out..   still same issue though.

Comment: Pal, you're defining`<div id="mapid">` and then calling `L.map("map")` - please double-check this is not just a simple typo.

Comment: @IvanSanchez  thanks..  I'll update the post but it's the exact same issue.  You are correct I had them miss-matched but it didn't resolve it.   I can inspect the dom tree and clearly see my div id="mapid" being there and rendering with the proper height.  Still Leaflet will not see it.

Comment: OK..   I think I resolved it..   I had to pass the div as an element and not let Leaflet look for it by ID.  (then add in the style sheet)

Comment: It seems that you found the answer by yourself about 30 seconds before I could hit "send" on my answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to instantiate a Leaflet map before its container is in the DOM is a [known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647735/leaflet-map-container-not-found), with a known solution:

> The `<div id="leafletmap">` must be added to the dom **before** calling `L.map('leafletmap')`.

But you already know this, because you're making a very good and specific question:

> Is there a way in [Leaflet 1.4] to find and use a shadow DOM-based `mapid` div?

The answer is "no, but".

If you read carefully the Leaflet API reference, you'll notice that a [`L.Map` can be instantiated in two ways](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-l-map): either by providing the `id` of the `HTMLElement` that will be the map's container, or by *providing the `HTMLElement` instance* of the container.

In other words, something along the lines of:

```
var mapdiv = document.createElement('div');
shadow.appendChild(mapdiv);
var map = L.map(mapdiv)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following resolves it now.

Needed to pass the map div as an element not provide an id string for Leaflet to find.  The also pass along the CSS.

```
import * as L from './leaflet/leaflet-src.esm.js';

(function () {
    class GDMap extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();

            let shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
            var mapdiv = document.createElement('div');
            mapdiv.setAttribute('id', 'mapid');
            // mapdiv.setAttribute('style', 'height:180px');
            mapdiv.style.height = "180px";
            mapdiv.innerHTML = ' <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="crossorigin=""/>';
            shadow.appendChild(mapdiv);

            var map = L.map(mapdiv).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

            L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'

            }).addTo(map);

            L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
                .openPopup();

        }
    }
    window.customElements.define('geodex-map', GDMap);
})();
```